# Describing an euler rotation with only axial rotations

Tags: linear-algebra

I make levels for a popular videogame. In this game there's an entity which I often use, called a `func_rotating`. This is an entity that rotates around either the Z (default), X or Y axes with a constant angular velocity. The rotation can be reversed if necessary.

Entities such as `prop_dynamic`s (models that can move or change skin) or other `func_rotating`s can be "parented" to this entity, and they will mirror any translation or rotation of their parent. By virtue of their parent's mirroring of its parent's, it will also mirror its grandparent's (etc) rotations and translations.

I am trying to encode a rotation with an arbitrary angular velocity (i.e, a 3-vector whose direction encodes the axis of rotation and magnitude encodes the rate of rotation in rad/s) as a system of sequentially parented entities.

In other words, I need to find a combination of two or three sequentially-parented `func_rotating` entities who share an origin, that will perform a rotation around an arbitrary axis at an arbitrary speed.

Bonus points if someone can give insight into how rotation matricies, quaternion multiplications or Euler angle transformations translate to this. Extra bonus points if you can describe the affine transformations that would arise if the entities did not share an origin (the origin describing point on the axis of rotation).

Comment: Wait don't tell me it's as simple as having the e_i-value of the rotational velocity vector as the rotation speed of the e_i-axis rotating for e_i as x, y and z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the axial rotations to get a 3D rotation about the axis you want (since rotations in 3D can be represented as pseudovectors that permit vector addition). You should decide which vector-direction is your desired rotation axis and then obtain (calculate) the unit vector in that direction, then rescale this vector by your desired rotation speed.

It wasn't clear to me what you were asking about the entities not sharing an origin, you can always perform a rotation about the origin of the entity followed by an affine translation